# Angular how to add one day of an object Date?

Tags: angular, date

I get an object Date whith format ( YYYY-MM-DD) and I want to create an object and add one day to this object ( if my object is 2020-03-10, I would like to get 2020-03-11), how can I do ?

```
this.mypensionsort.dtFin //the object Date
const dateDayPlusOne = new Date(this.mypensionsort.dtFin.getDate() + 1); //Doesn't work
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript `getDate` and `setDate` function to achieve this.
see the example

```js
const mydate="2020-03-10";
const newDate = new Date(mydate);
const result = new Date(newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1));
console.log(result);
```